# Adding comment as "most commented" on my view?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails 3 blog, which has Article and Comment models in `has_many` and `belongs_to` associations. When an article comment is > 3, I should see it in my application.html.erb views so I can call it "most commented".

```
<div class="span2">
 <%=image_tag ("Lekki_Gardens_new.gif")  %>
<br><br>
  <b><p>News update</p></b>  
  <% @articles.first(4).each do |article| %>
   <%=image_tag article.avatar_url(:lilthumb).to_s, :class=>"img-polaroid" %><br>
  <%= link_to article.name, article%><hr>
   <% end %>


</div
```

Comment: the code of this post is not really the hint of the post

Comment: then post the appropriate code to give you clear answer..

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:counter_cache` option in your article model and then use a scope to retrieve the most commented ones.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, counter_cache: true
  scope :most_commented, where('comments_count > 3')
end
```

And then in your template:

```
<% Article.most_commented.each do |article| %>
  <% # anything you want %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yes man i got Unknown key: counter_cache thanks for your reply

Comment: Does your article class inherit from activerecord::base?

Comment: **bold**class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
  attr_accessible :type_id, :name, :content, :avatar, :avatar_cache, :remote_avatar_url, :category_id
  validates_presence_of :name, :content 
  has_many :comments, counter_cache: true
  scope :most_commented, where('comments_count > 3')
  belongs_to :category
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
 
 def to_param
    [id, name.parameterize].join("-")
  end

end

Comment: You must add a column comments_count in your schema to make it work properly

Comment: please give me a clue on how i can add the  it to the schema

Comment: well i saw the schema but what kind of feild is it?

Comment: Add a new migration with the following command `rails g migration AddCommentsCountToArticle`. It will create a new file in db/migrate/xxx_add_comments_count_to_article.rb. Then in the change function add this `add_column :articles, :comments_count, :integer`. and then run `rake:db:migrate`

Comment: yes it generate this file  db/migrate/20130327164257_add_comments_count_to_article.rb

Comment: what do i do before the migration?

Comment: Add the following code in the body of the change function: `add_column :articles, :comments_count, :integer`

Comment: when i remove the counter_cache from the model it reture noting to my views

Comment: Which version of ruby/rails do you use?